# Understanding MX records with C#

Tags: c#, smtp, mx-record

I am probably missing a piece of understanding about how mail transfer works in order to implement it.

I want to implement an SMTP server, it receives an email message from the client, then it looks for the recipient MX record of the domain in order to deliver it there.

What I don't fully understand is what happens next, does it connect to that domain by IP? to which port?

The example I am looking at is Gmail, it MX server is gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com, does my program need to connect to this domain on what port?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt

Short Answer:

When delivering email.  Look for mx records of the domain name in question.

If MXs exist for for the domain attempt to connect to them via port 25 and deliver you mail per RFC Above.  You connect to them in order of preference listed.  Lower Numbers have higher preference.  If equi-cost MX's are present, you are free to pick one at random.  If that one doesn't answer try the same Weight MX before going higher in the chain.  If no mxs answer then queue mail and try again..

If no MXs exist try to deliver to the 'A' Record on the well know port of 25 (SMTP).

But really, read the RFCs and become familiar with them, it will help out a lot..

And somewhat related.  If you are implementing a SMTP server for use on the internet,  Make sure that you have the ability to accept SMTP authenticated email on the Submission port (587) as well as the standard port of 25. As lots of networks have outbound blocks on port 25 for spam abatement purposes..

Comment: O.k. but what is the difference between a mail server logging to gmail server transfering a message and a user using gmail as its smtp server needing to identify itself with gmail (using gmail as an example ofcourse).

Comment: The difference is between MTA and MUA (Mail Transfer Agent and Mail User Agent). If you are a mail server, then you are an MTA, So you are connecting to their mail exchangers, You do not have an existing relationship with google(IE are not a user)  you are delivering email to them. IF all your client is doing it sending email via google, you don't use the MX's you use the SMTP relay users (normally on port 587 along with SMTP AUTH and TLS )

Comment: So if i am understanding you right, if i transfer a message to the exchange server with a recipient not on gmail domain it will be rejected?

Comment: Correct, if you connect to gmail's MX server and attempt to deliver to a non local recipient it will deny the relay attempt.  If you connect to gmail on their relay servers and auth using your gmail account it will relay the mail for you,  But at that point you are an MUA, not an MTA. IE client vs server.

Comment: Great, just the piece I was missing!
so if i want to implement an smtp server i need to start two different servers in order one of them to be a mx server?

Comment: You don't need to have 2 servers. Your server can deliver locally for domains it knows about, and can queue deliver to other domains. Most mail servers do this, and can be configured to allow it.  IE look in local domain table, if local try to deliver locally, if not local then check to see if permission to relay, then attempt to deliver if the user has permission.  The checking for permission is very important. Since if you let anybody relay without some for of auth your server will be an open relay and turned into a spam cannon pretty quickly..

Answer (score 0):

SMTP operates on port 25. This [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sendmailcsharp.aspx) shows a simplistic local example using C# to send/receive mail.